# PHP RecursiveIteratorIterator: The system cannot find the path specified?

Tags: php, spl, php-5.4, spl-autoload-register

I have this error when I want to autoload classes with `RecursiveIteratorIterator` and `spl_autoload_register`,

> uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message
>   'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(): The system cannot find the
>   path specified. (code: 3)

What does it mean?

Below is my class autoloader,

```
function autoload_multiple_directory($class_name){

    // List all the class directories in the array.
    $array_directories = array(
        'core/controller/', 
        'core/model/',
        'core/helper/',
        'core/ext/'
    );

    $parts = explode('\\', $class_name);

    // Set the class file name.
    $file_name = end($parts).'.php';

    foreach($array_directories as $path_directory){

        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path_directory),
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
        );

        foreach ($iterator as $fileObject) {
            if ($fileObject->isDir()) {
                $files[] = str_replace('\\', '/', $fileObject->getPathname()).'/';
            }
        }


    }



    $array_directories = array_merge($array_directories,$files);

    // Loop the array.
    foreach($array_directories as $path_directory){
        if(file_exists(WEBSITE_DOCROOT.$path_directory.$file_name)){

            include WEBSITE_DOCROOT.$path_directory.$file_name;
        } 
    }
}


spl_autoload_register('autoload_multiple_directory');
```

The error line is pointing to `new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path_directory),` why?

Comment: because the path is wrong! Try var_dump($path_directory) and check if the path is actually physically alright.

Answer (score 1):

I must use absolute path in `new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(WEBSITE_DOCROOT.$path_directory)` as the init.php is called via ajax sometimes.